# (1 2) reported an error of invalid function

Tags: lisp

Upon reading [Cons-Cell-types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Cons-Cell-Type)

```
ELISP> '(1 2)
(1 2)

ELISP> (1 2)
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: 1
```

The reported error confused me,
How could an integer of 1 be interred as  a function which is invalid.

Comment: Now the question is: what would you expect `(1 2)` to do?
You probably heard of Lisp prefix syntax: `(function-name arg-0 arg-1 ... arg-n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the paragraph is about *reading* and *printing* lisp forms:

> The read syntax and printed representation for lists are identical, and consist of a left parenthesis, an arbitrary number of elements, and a right parenthesis.

When encoutering `(1 2)`, the interpreter builds a list of two elements, which, when printed, is also printed as `(1 2)`. In a Read-Eval-Print-Loop, however, the form being read is immediately evaluated, and the [evaluation rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Function-Forms) says that:

> If the first element of a list being evaluated is a Lisp function object, byte-code object or primitive function object, then that list is a function call.

The result is different when you write the list quoted:

```
'(1 2)
```

Here above, the quote syntax translates the form into the following one (at read-time):

```
(quote (1 2))
```

And the quote operator is special in that when evaluated, it does not evaluate its subexpression, but returns it as-is. That's why `'(1 2)` in the REPL evaluates as the literal list enclosed under the quote, namely `(1 2)`.

Comment: so quote is escape.